# Unable to improve validation accuracy though training is 100% and how to feed images extracted from videos to deep learning model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, gesture-recognition

I am building a gesture recognition system using 20bn's jester dataset. Currently, I am working on only 4 classes. Dataset consists of images extracted from videos at 12 frames/sec rate.  I built 2 models, 3D-CNN and CNN-LSTM  but getting accuracy around 25-30% only using keras and Tensorflow.

```
Dataset looks like X_train = (651, 1, 128, 128, 22)
X_valid=(260, 1, 128, 128, 22)
Y_train=(651, 4)
Y_valid = (260, 4)
```

Image size is 128*128 with 1 channel, I am appending 22 images at a time with 651 as a total number of samples.
3d-CNN architecture

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution3D(32, (3, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1), input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, img_depth),
                            activation='relu', data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((3, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, kernel_initializer='normal'))

    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

CNN-LSTM model architecture

```
(651, 22, 128, 128, 1)
(260, 22, 128, 128, 1)
(651, 4)
(260, 4)
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2),
                                     activation='relu', padding='same'), input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                                     kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))


    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))


    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))


    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))


    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                                     padding='same', activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))


    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Dataset is balanced with 100 gestures from each class and I ran the model for 100 epoch. Is the architecture correct? I also have doubts regarding feeding the images. As I am working on videos so I need an extra dimension to extract the temporal features so appended 22 images in 1 array first and kept on appending similarly, is it the right way to do? First I tried with 12 also instead of 22 but same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are a few suggestions

- your training n is 400, I 'feel' like this n is too small, i recommend increasing the training dataset to maybe like 500*4. remember to shuffle the data when writing the training data and enable random shuffle per batch during training.
- is the data normalized (from 0 to 1, or zero mean unit variance)?
- are you sure each sample have 22 images in the training dataset, and you zero pad in the time channel for the samples if they do not have 22 frames?
- have you tried varying optimizers, learning rates?
- for both architecture, the bottle neck segment, I would recommend at least 2 layers of dense layers.
- for 3D-CNN, i recommend adding a few more cnn layers, like what you did with the cnn-lstm.
- for both architectures, beside the last output layer, consistently use the same activation 'relu', no need to mix and match (your CNN-LSTM have a sigmoid in the dense layer)
- for both architectures, reduce dropout probability to maybe 0.2 (if you are using keras).
- if above changes are not helping, add in batch normalization for each layer.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the suggestion. I'll try to increase the dataset and follow other suggestions. Yes data is normalized and shuffled. Instead of Zero pad, I fill it with images of the next class to keep the sample size 22, is that wrong?

Comment: Each sample (1, 1, 128, 128, 22) should come from one video clip. Also ideally the z dimension should have the max z from all samples, perhaps some videos have more than 22frames? If there are some videos with 48 frames, zero pad the rest of the frames and make the x shape  (None, 1, 128, 128, 44).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I increased the dataset size to 500 videos for each class and z dimension size to 32 to fit the videos in one array. Now testing accuracy increased to 70%.

Comment: nice! would appreciate it if you accept my solution as the answer.